# How to remove chat history from a Microsoft Teams Client running in Kiosk Mode?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, kiosk, kiosk-mode

On a Kiosk running a Windows PC in a reception area type setting, we would like to run a Microsoft Team Client which can be used to interact with another Teams App (Bot) or a Teams User

We can assign a generic Windows/Azure AD ID so that the Kiosk Windows PC is auto logged in with that ID and then consequently logs into Microsoft Teams with that generic ID (Reception24Kiosk@customer.com for example).

A visitor walks up to the Kiosk.  They can then use the already running Teams client  to start a chat with the Teams App (bot) or another Teams User.

As Teams client history is persistent, how do we clean up any chat history in the Teams client so that NEXT walk up visitor who uses the Kiosk PC can not see previous chat messages in the Teams client.

We are aware of Teams retention policies and a custom policy could be created for auto deletion but that seems to be measured in number of days. That is too long with this application.

Any way to clear out the chat history on each login to the Teams client (in which case we can somehow force logout the user after each walk up) or another way to reduce the chat history retention to a few minutes?

We have looked at the Microsoft Graph as well, and could not find a way to delete an entire 1:1 chat for a user (even with Delegated permissions)

Any other suggestions from admins who have tried to use Teams in the Kiosk Mode with a generic ID?

Answer (score 0):

Teams client chat history is persistent one. There is no provision to clear out the history on each login. There is Teams retention policy for auto-deletion but as it is measured in number of days, that won't be applicable for your application as you mentioned.

Comment: Is there a way using Graph assuming we get the right app or delegated permissions?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do so using graph. Thanks!